# POI XSSF reading all columns not just all defined columns - results not expected

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-poi, xssf

Is there a way to not read the entire Excel documents row, I'm reading the cell's defined in the document, but, it's pulling in the entire sheet's columns???

I'm converting an Excel document to a CSV document. I am getting this result.

```
Aircraft ID (FADEC_SHIP_POS),Fleet (Fleet Name),Fault Date (TIMESTAMP or FADEC_DATE_TIME),Fault ID (FADEC_ID),Fault Description (FADEC_FAULT_DESCRIPTION),Priority (FADEC_PRIORITY),ATA,Flight Phase (FM),Report Type (REPORT_TYPE),Flight Number (FLT),Origin (ORIG),Destination (DEST),Site Reference Name,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I don't need all those extra undefined columns, (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)

also, there can be empty values in the row's defined columns: - these are expected and needed

```
6808-1,B757,2019-09-25 20:50:18,351-21A,P(S) 351-21,3,,Climb,901,1278,,,Sprint Airlines
```

my class

```
public class XlsxToCsv implements Processor {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(XlsxToCsv.class.getName());

 private static final String CSV_SEPERATOR_CHAR=",";
 private static final String NEW_LINE_CHARACTER="\r\n";

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    log.info("Entering XLSX Excel to CSV ...");

    int sheetIdx = 0;
    byte[] in = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
    String out = excelToCSV(in,sheetIdx);
    exchange.getIn().setBody(out);

    log.info("Exiting XLSX Excel to CSV ...");
}

private String excelToCSV(byte[] xlsxFile, int sheetIdx) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String cellVal = "";

    try {
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xlsxFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    XSSFSheet workSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);

    for (int i = 0; i < workSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        XSSFRow row = workSheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
            cellVal = getCellValueAsString(workBook, row.getCell(j));
                if ( j == row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() - 1) {
                    sb.append(cellVal).append(NEW_LINE_CHARACTER);
                } else {
                    sb.append(cellVal).append(CSV_SEPERATOR_CHAR);
                }
        }
    }
    workBook.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
    private String getCellValueAsString(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFCell cell) {
        String cellValue = "";
        if (cell != null) {
            CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();
            if (cellType == CellType.FORMULA) {
                FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                cellType = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
            }
            switch (cellType) {
                case STRING:
                    cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    Double doubleValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    int intValue = doubleValue.intValue();
                    cellValue = Integer.toString(intValue);
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    cellValue = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    cellValue = cell.getErrorCellString();
                    break;
                case BLANK:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return cellValue;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the template I'm using had spaces entered in the last elements in the spreadsheet, I removed and cleaned up the xlsx template and it is working as expected.

always learning, I wouldn't expect that, but, it is what it is,